# How to format output like this

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, formatting, output

My code is like this so far :

```cpp
void matrix::print(int colWidth) const
{
    cout << getRows() << " x " << getCols() << endl;
    cout << "-";
    for (unsigned int d = 0; d < getCols(); d++) {
        cout << "--------";
    }

    cout << endl;
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < getRows(); x++) {
        cout << "|";
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < getCols(); y++) {
            cout << setw(colWidth) << at(x, y) << " |";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "-";
    for (unsigned int d = 0; d < getCols(); d++) {
        cout << "--------";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

But the output depends on the `colWidth` which will be the space between each number printed. So how can I adjust my dashes to be printed like the following no matter the `colWidth` it should align.

One output should look like this:

[image]

Second output is like this:

[image]

Comment: If you want to pretty print your matrix you'll have to calculate the width of the longer number (after turning it into a string), before doing the print: 1) walk all numbers of the matrix, turn them into a string, save the longest string size; 2) decide column width (e.g. longest string size or longest string size plus some spacing; 3) print.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: Instead of a fixed number of dashes, you need to print a variable number. Probably `colWidth + 3`, or thereabout. I would add a call `print_dashes(getCols(), colWidth);` and then adjust that function until the tests work,

Comment: You don’t actually have to convert to string twice to get the max width and print. To get the max width just use log10 + 1 (and for floats with fixed precision, just add N digits + 1).

Comment: @Dúthomhas Beautiful, I wasn't aware of that (or had forgotten)! I understand +1 also for negative numbers. Thank you.

Comment: For negative numbers + 2. :O)

Comment: Though, now that I’ve said all that, you could just repurpose a matrix using std::string as the element type and cache all the converted strings to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column width is a parameter, you're almost done with your code. Just turn the `cout<<"--------"` into:

`std::cout << std::string(getCols()*(colWidth + 2) + 1, '-');`

That code prints a string of dashes, which width is: number of matrix columns, times column width plus 2, plus 1:

- Plus 2 because you are appending a `" |"` to each column.
- Plus 1 because you are adding a `'|'` at the beginning of each row.

You may want to check for empty matrices at the beginning of your `print` method.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/h5T7WdcGn)

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iomanip>  // setw
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <vector>

class matrix
{
public:
    matrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>> l) : v{l} {}
    
    size_t getRows() const { return v.size(); }
    size_t getCols() const { if (v.size()) { return v[0].size(); } return 0; }
    int at(size_t x, size_t y) const { return v.at(x).at(y); }

    void print(int colWidth) const
    {
        std::cout << "Matrix: " << getRows() << " x " << getCols() << "\n";

        // +2 due to " |", +1 due to initial '|'
        std::cout << std::string(getCols()*(colWidth + 2) + 1, '-') << "\n";
        
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < getRows(); x++) {
            std::cout << "|";
            for (unsigned y = 0; y < getCols(); y++) {
                std::cout << std::setw(colWidth) << at(x, y) << " |";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << std::string(getCols()*(colWidth + 2) + 1, '-') << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{};
};

int main()
{
    matrix m{{1, 2}, {-8'000, 100'000}, {400, 500}};
    m.print(10);
}

// Outputs
//
//   Matrix: 3 x 2
//   -------------------------
//   |         1 |         2 |
//   |     -8000 |    100000 |
//   |       400 |       500 |
//   -------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Very glad to be helpful!